# Single and double click on editor

Tags: extjs, combobox, editor

I have an editor (combobox) and I want to call different function on single click and double click.This is my editor

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
field: Ext.widget('combo', {
    editable: false,
    allowBlank: false,
    width: 100,
    store: MyStore,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    listeners: {
        eventforSingleClick: function (){            },
        eventforDoubleClick: function (){            }
    }
})
```

});

Which event listeners I should implement for single and double click events?

Comment: This might help - https://nraykov.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/ext-js-grid-rowclick-and-rowdblclick-issues/

Comment: thanks ths is work for me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is best solution, but you can do something like this:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        editable: false,
        allowBlank: false,
        width: 100,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(combo) {
                combo.getEl().on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Clicked!');
                });
                combo.getEl().on('dblclick', function() {
                    console.log('Double clicked!');
                });
            }
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/185g)

Comment: thank you, this also work. But solution with timeOut is best for me